# Multiline PageTitle with android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

in an android app, I use a `TabLayout` to display multiple `Fragments` in a single activity.
I want the tabs to be labeled with icons and a two line heading.

In the Activity's onCreate I initialise the `SectionsPageAdapter` and the `TabLayout` like:

```
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new 
    SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    // add a PageChangeListener to be able to detect which tab is activated
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){
        ...
    });

    ...
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);

    //Set icons for tabs
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic1);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic2);
}
```

And in the `SectionpagerAdapter` I define the **PageTitles** using:

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "First \nTab";
        case 1:
            return "Second \nTab";
        case 2:
            return "Third \nTab";
    }
    return null;
}
```

But when i run the app, the **PageTitles** aren't broken in two lines, but shortened with ... to fit the screen.

How to enable multiline **PageTitles** for the Tabs?

Answer (score 0):

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(yuorTabView);
```

And you can customize your own TabView